# Display count of records from table based on length of time active?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table with user info that contains datetime column having their registration date (ie, 2015-01-01) called "added", how can I show the count of all records registered/active per following periods:

1) less than a year
2) between 1 and 2 years
3) between 2 and 3 years
4) ... so on for as long back as the "added" years go.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS count, YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(added) AS years
FROM users
GROUP BY YEAR(added)
```

But that calc is off, since it just groups the results by YEAR, not by the actual date from today. As in, someone registered in December of 2014 would still come out showing as count "1" on January 2015... even though in reality, the actual registration date should be taken into consideration, not just the YEAR.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT Count(*) AS count, 
SUM(IF (DATE_ADD(added, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) > NOW(), 1, 0)) AS num_1year,
SUM(IF (DATE_ADD(added, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) < NOW() AND DATE_ADD(added, INTERVAL 2 YEAR) > NOW(), 1, 0)) AS num_2year,
SUM(IF (DATE_ADD(added, INTERVAL 2 YEAR) < NOW() AND DATE_ADD(added, INTERVAL 3 YEAR) > NOW(), 1, 0)) AS num_3year
FROM users
```

Comment: beauty! that's pretty much it... missing a comma at the end of line 3, but that's pretty much it! thank you... all makes sense now.

Comment: How would you count only unique users per year? As in, if someone was added in 2014, I wouldn't count him in 2015, assuming the user_id is a field where user IDs are stored, and a single user_id could have registered for multiple courses/memberships over the years. Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't already the case, as there is a unique row per user in the users table ?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the `GROUP BY` statements,  aggregate function is needed in the select part.

```
SELECT Count(*) AS count, YEAR(CURDATE() - YEAR(added) AS years
FROM users                ^^^ no way to group
GROUP BY YEAR(added)
```

Calculate the date diff using the [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function.

```
SELECT Count(*) AS count, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE() - added)/365) AS year_diff
FROM users              
GROUP BY years_diff
```

PS: this is not quite accurate, as assuming the datediff 365 as a year. But it support any year range, you won't have to change this to support year diff from n to n+1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1) less than a year

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM users WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, added, NOW()) < 12
```

2) between 1 and 2 years

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM users WHERE DATEDIFF(added, NOW()) BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```